# ResponseListener changes Content-Type of assets

Tags: symfony, assetic

In my dev environment after adding a response listener the content type of my css files switched from text/css to text/html. My goal is just to add some caching headers to all responses of my symfony application.

**Service definition:**

```
response_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListeners\ResponseListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response }
```

**Service class:**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListeners;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class ResponseListener
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        // while testing I do nothing special here
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

**Assetic config:**

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: true
    bundles:        [ AppBundle ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

**Twig tag:**

```
{% stylesheets
    'bundles/app/css/login.css'
    filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

With text/html as the content type the css is not rendered.
Removing just the service definition makes it work correctly again.
In prod environment it works with or without the response listener and js files are no problem at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had a really similar issue and although I didn't went to trace it exactly on the core bundles of symfony, I think this is due to the fact that, on development instance, assetic do use a controller to render the CSS.

I actually stopped looking at the moment I found, that, like you, my `config_dev.yml` stated :

```
assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

So I figured out that when you try to play with the response object in symfony, the requested format gets somehow lost while listening on the response. [Symfony's own ResponseListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ResponseListener.php#L49) seems to [set text/html as a defaullt](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php#L284) because there is no content type defined.

The fix is quite easy though : 
In the class `ResponseListener`, our listening function become

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    $response = $event->getResponse();

    // We do get the params of the route
    $route_params = $event->getRequest()->get('_route_params');

    // And we figure out if it should be in a specific format
    if(isset($route_params['_format'])) {

        // getMimeType function on the Request object come in handy for this job
        $format = $event->getRequest()->getMimeType($route_params['_format']);

        // Then we just reinstate the right Content Type
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', $format);
    }
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

While you will never have this issue in production environnement like you state it, because your assets are dumped by the command line assetic tool, which is not a controller.

And actually, if you do something like this in your `ResponseListener`

```
die($event->getRequest()->get('_controller'));
```

And that you navigate to a css file by its direct url you would see this display :

[image: assetic.controller:render]

Which totally validate the fact that the css gets constructed **on the fly** by the **render** view of **assetic bundle controller** when you have that configuration stated above.

Comment: Absolutly correct, I traced it down to be happening when the event is porcessed. This is kind of a bug. I'll edit your ansower to include the exact line where it happens.

Comment: Nice digging in the root of the issue